# Explanation about 'taggable_friends' permission review process

Tags: facebook

In my facebook application i need to access user's friends informations like the first name, in order to do that i use the taggable_friends permission. All works fine with me (the admin), test users (created through facebook) and real testers.
My problem is when i submit the permission to facebook review team, they continue to answer me in this way : 
"I am unable to reproduce the taggable friends permission because my friend's list never appeared within your Canvas platform. Please look into this and resubmit when the permissions' visibility is clear. Thank you."
So, I find out the "fake user" used by the review team (Donald Duck) has granted all permissions (among them the needed user_friends) but trying to access his taggable_friends facebook Graph API gives this error : 
'(#10) To use taggable_friends on behalf of people who are not admins, developers and testers of your app, your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review'.
But i'm actually submitting it. I'm confused by that.
Do someone have the same issue in submitting this permission? Or possible explanations?

Comment: may i ask what for you need the first name of the user friends, and the friend list in general?

Comment: You are not allowed to use that endpoint for anything else but actually tagging people.

Comment: The business logic of my application it's not the point, i guess. The problem is that only with the review guy the retrieval through that edge doesn't work. Regardless from my purpose he isn't able to just try my app.